# Methods stripped from object when passed via Metro.call()

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am currently trying to make the [node-hue-api](https://github.com/peter-murray/node-hue-api) npm library work in my MeteorJS project. I already got the bridge search and connection working (although it does not follow the Meteor way entirely). I am however stuck on searching lights.

To get an authenticated client I defined the following code in my bridge component methods:

```
import { Settings } from '../../settings/settings';
import { HueApi } from 'node-hue-api';

Meteor.methods({
    'philipsHue.bridges.client'() {
        const hueSettings = Settings.findOne({ type: 'philips-hue' });
        return new HueApi(hueSettings.hostname, hueSettings.username);
    }
});
```

In my light methods (different file) I am now calling this method to get an authenticated client:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'lights.scan'() {
        var hueClient = new HueApi(Meteor.call('philipsHue.bridges.client'));
        hueClient.lights().then((val) => {
            val.lights.forEach(function (hueLight) {
                let dbLight = Lights.findOne({ id: hueLight.id });

                if (dbLight) {
                    // we already have a db copy of this light, check for changes
                }
                else {
                    // we need a new local copy for this light
                    dbLight.insert(hueLight);
                }
            })
        });
    }
});
```

The returned HueApi object has the correct variables, but it has been stripped of all its methods - leading me to an undefined method error. This only happens with objects passed through `Meteor.call()`, if I create the object within the same function the methods are all there.

This is the class of the library I have problems with: [GitHub](https://github.com/peter-murray/node-hue-api/blob/master/hue-api/index.js)

What is causing this method stripping behavior? How can I fix it?

Comment: please show the code of your other file as you mentioned where this `lights.scan` is actually failing.

Comment: It's in the link at the bottom. The code of the file itself works fine, but the method scope doesn't seem to cooperate with Meteor

Comment: Meteor methods work over DDP, and I am almost certain they only send the JSON and not a full-fledged "object" with methods and such.  You can view what Meteor sends through method calls and the like by using Chrome's dev tools and going to the Network tab, then filtering on WS (Web Sockets).  Just as you would have to `transform` the results of a Collection query result, you will probably have to do something similar to make the raw JSON transform back to the full object you desire.  Keep in mind that JavaScript doesn't really deal with "Objects", but rather uses prototypes to simulate them.

Comment: @CodeChimp that was it! I'm still very new to MeteorJS so the simple stuff gets me sometimes. Thanks for the hint & explanation. :) if you want you can post it as question reply and I'll mark it as solved for the extra rep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Posted from comment above...**

Meteor methods work over DDP, and I am almost certain they only send the JSON and not a full-fledged "object" with methods and such. You can view what Meteor sends through method calls and the like by using Chrome's dev tools and going to the Network tab, then filtering on WS (Web Sockets). Just as you would have to transform the results of a Collection query result, you will probably have to do something similar to make the raw JSON transform back to the full object you desire. Keep in mind that JavaScript doesn't really deal with "Objects", but rather uses prototypes to simulate them.